# BERT vs GPT architectural, conceptual and implemetational differences

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, bert, transformer, gpt

In the [BERT paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf), I learnt that BERT is encoder-only model, that is it involves only transformer encoder blocks.

In the [GPT paper](https://cdn.openai.com/research-covers/language-unsupervised/language_understanding_paper.pdf), I learnt that GPT is decoder-only model, that is it involves only transformer decoder blocks.

I was guessing whats the difference. I know following difference between encoder and decoder blocks: GPT Decoder looks only at previously generated tokens and learns from them and not in right side tokens. BERT Encoder gives attention to tokens on both sides.

But I have following doubts:

**Q1.** GPT2,3 focuses on new/one/zero short learning. Cant we build new/one/zero short learning model with encoder-only architecture like BERT?

**Q2.** Huggingface `Gpt2Model` contains `forward()` method. I guess, feeding single data instance to this method is like doing one shot learning?

**Q3.** I have implemented neural network model which utilizes output from `BertModel` from hugging face. Can I simply swap `BertModel` class with `GPT2Model` with some class and will it. The return value of [`Gpt2Model.forward`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/gpt2.html#transformers.GPT2Model.forward) does indeed contain `last_hidden_state` similar to [`BertModel.forward`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#transformers.BertModel.forward). So, I guess swapping out `BertModel` with `Gpt2Model` will indeed work, right?

**Q4.** Apart from being decoder-only and encoder-only, auto-regressive vs non-auto-regressive and whether or not accepting tokens generated so far as input, what high level architectural / conceptual differences GPT and BERT have?

Answer (score 5):

To start with your last question: you correctly say that BERT is an encoder-only model trained with the masked language-modeling objective and operates non-autoregressively. GPT-2 is a decode-only model trained using the left-to-right language objective and operates autoregressively. Other than that, there are only technical differences in hyper-parameters, but no other conceptual differences.

BERT (other masked LMs) could also be used for zero- or few-shot learning, but in a slightly different way. There is a method called [PET](https://aclanthology.org/2021.eacl-main.20/) (Pattern-
Exploiting Training). It uses the language modeling abilities of BERT via templates. E.g., for sentiment analysis, you can do something like:

```
<...text of the review..><.TEMPLATE......> <  ?  >.
The pizza was fantastic. The restaurant is [MASK].
```

Then you check what score was would `good` and `bad` get at the position of the `[MASK]` token.

Working with the GPT-2 model is not that straightforward as with BERT. Calling the `forward` method returns the hidden states of GPT-2 given the input you provided that can be further used in a model. You can use hidden states of GPT-2 as contextual embeddings, the same way that you the output of BERT, however, this is not how GPT-2 is usually used.

The usual way of using GPT-2 sampling from the model. This means that you provide a prompt (as plain text) and hope that the model will continue in a reasonable way. There are many tutorials on how to generate from the GPT-2 models, e.g., this blog post by [Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-generate).